# How to encode "g1 = b ? g : 0" as LP constraints?

Tags: linear-programming

I have:

```
var g;
var g1;
var b, binary;
```

I need to have

> g = g1, if b = true
>   0 = g1, if b = false

Both g and g1 are limited: 0..1

How to encode this as linear constraints in the linear program?

Comment: This is essentially a multiplication: `g1 = b*g`. For a formulation see e.g. [here](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2017/02/multiplication-of-binary-with.html).

Answer (score 0):

`g1 <= b` and `g1 >= g - (1 - b)`

*Edit:* Additionally `g >= g1 - (1 - b)` is required to cover the case of `b = 1, g = 0, g1 = 1`.

Comment: This is not 100% correct. E.g. `b=1, g=0, g1=1` is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

```
g1 <= b
-M(1-b) + g <= g1 <= g + M(1-b)
```

with M being an arbitrarily large constant

if `b = 0`, then `g = 0` due to the first constraint, and the second becomes redundant, `-M <= g1 <= M` (`M >> g`).

if `b = 1`, then `g1`, according to the first constraint, can be either 0 or 1, but the second constraint becomes
`g <= g1 <= g`, that is, `g1 = g`